# How to Install an executable as a Windows Service

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-service, windows-7

I have an executable that doesn't require any interaction with the user and I want to install it as a Windows service; what do I need to have and do to make that happen?

- I didn't write the app; I don't have the source and not willing to have it.
- It's not a .Net app; can't use InstallUtil.exe
- I'm on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about Windows 7, but the SC and SrvAny utilities from the Windows Server 2003 resource kit still worked on Server 2008 the last time I checked; I've used this technique myself to get PDFCreator running as a service on our file/print box:

- Grab "srvany.exe" from the Server 2003 Resource Kit and copy it to your Server 2008 box.
- Use "sc" to create a new service that launches "srvany":

`sc create NewService binPath= C:\Windows\System32\srvany.exe DisplayName= "My Custom Service".`

(Those spaces between the equal sign and the value are actually required by SC.  No, I don't know why either.)

- Use Regedit to create a key called "Parameters" in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NewService\Parameters).  Inside that key, create a string value called "Application" and enter the full path to the application you are wanting to run as a service.
- Cross fingers, start service.

Comment: So the answer is "No, but there is a workaround" :) Anyway, I'll mark this as an answer because it worked in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Srvany will do the basic job of running your executable as a service but be careful as it falls short in some areas. Check out [this page comparing Srvany to our commercial alternative](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/srvany.html) for the details.

Comment: AlwaysUp guys has their own console to create and monitor services and not doing it from Windows Services console, which is a minus for me; plus, it's too expensive for my need.